# What angle does the slopping bottom make with the horizontal?

Tags: geometry

The figure shows the cross section of 
 a swimming pool. What angle does the slopping bottom make with the horizontal?

[image]
how can i solve that

Comment: The picture has an arrow on the bottom of the pool without a number attached. You need that number to determine the angle.

Comment: this is full questions .. there is no given more

Comment: What is "opposite'"about that figure?

Comment: The question as presented cannot be answered with a single definite number--that is, we cannot say it is 3 degrees, or that it is 30 degrees, although either of those _might_ be an answer if the missing information were filled in a certain way. If the length of the bottom arrow is a variable then the answer is a function of that variable. Notice that zoli has edited the figure to give that variable the name $a,$ which makes it possible to give a formula for the answer. You now have two answers equal to each other, and I think this is the best we can do with the given information.

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ is not given then the answer will depend on $a$. According to the following figure

[image]
we can tell that

$$\color{green}\gamma=\frac{\pi}2-\arctan\left(\tan(\color{blue}{\beta})\right)=\frac{\pi}2-\arctan\left(\frac{50-a}{2.5}\right).$$

This is how $\color{green}{\gamma}$ depends on $a$:

[image]

Comment: @Rahul: Sleepy, sorry, I've fixed my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$\tan ? = \frac {2.5}{50 -a}$ so

$? = \arctan \frac {2.5}{50 -a}$

That's the answer.

The exact value depends aon the value of $a$.  That is the formula for getting $?$ if you are given $a$.